# Eventhandler with multiple params and e.target

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just discovered that it is possible to bind multiple parameters through an addEventListener which is really cool.

This [link](https://toddmotto.com/avoiding-anonymous-javascript-functions/) explains a bit about multiple parameters through addEventListener.

My problem is i cant get "e.target.id" to work like it normally would?

Sample [here](http://xch07.wi2.sde.dk/sandbox/TEST.php)

CSS

```
#element{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="element">

</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener('click', toggleMenu.bind(null, "e", "param2"), false);
function toggleMenu(e, param2) {
    alert(e);
    alert(param2);

    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

Normally i would get the id by doing something similair to this

```
document.querySelector("#element2").addEventListener("click", somethings, false);
function somethings(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
}
```

So basically does anyone posses the knowledge and knows what i can do in this situation :) ?

Comment: I now get an undefined variable error :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding a string? All you need to do is:

```
document.querySelector("#element")
  .addEventListener('click', e => toggleMenu(e, param2), false);
```

Assumption: You have **`param2`** defined elsewhere in the code.

#### Edit:

If you need an answer solely using `bind`, you can do:

```
document.querySelector("#element")
  .addEventListener('click', toggleMenu.bind(null, param2), false);

function toggleMenu(param2, e) {
  /*use `e` whichever way you'd like*/
}
```

Comment: Well i found an easier way but that will do for an upvote since it helped me on the way :)

`document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener('click', toggleMenu.bind(null,"param2"), false);
            function toggleMenu(param2, e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                alert(e.target.id);
            }`

Answer (score 1):

Your event will be last argument in function handler, this is how bind actually works:

```
document.querySelector("#element").addEventListener('click', toggleMenu.bind(null, "e", "param2"), false);
function toggleMenu(param1, param2, event) {
    alert(param1); // "e"
    alert(param2); // "param2"

    alert(event); // Synthetic Mouse Event
}
```